# IIS 8.5: Disable access log for static content

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I using IIS 8.5 with access logs. But the IIS is also logging static content like css/js files and images. This is very useless and will cause unnecessary I/O. So is there a way to disable the access log for individual file types?

I came from linux to windows and in nginx i used something like this to solve the problem:

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|tgz|gz|rar|zip|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|ttf)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never come across one. Can you not filter in your log viewer of choice?

Remember that a request for /css/main.css does not have to return a file called main.css in the css folder on the file system.

A more obvious example is a request for /images/thumb/products/1123.jpg the file does not exist and the pipeline dynamically produces the thumbnail image on request.

Comment: The main problem is the performance. I've a bigger site with about 30-40 images, js- and css files per page. I have no dynamic generated css/js files or images, so I want to disable logging here to avoid wasting IO and storage.